# Update nth record in a table - sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to `update` `nth` record in a table

```
UPDATE ROW_NUMBER(3) table_name SET column1=value1, column2=value2
```

This is not working..

Comment: **`What Exactly do you want?`**

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I have re-framed the question now..

Comment: Why don't [Mahmoud Gamal](http://stackoverflow.com/users/722783/mahmoud-gamal) give an answer, as i think the above **`Comment`** is the **`Correct`** answer. :D

Answer (score 8):

Use a CTE if you are on SQL server 2005 upwards.

You can try the following(my syntax is getting rusty been on design too long):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY columnToUseForOrder) AS RowNumber,
           column1,
           column2
    FROM  table_Name
 )

 UPDATE CTE Set column1= value1, column2=value2 WHERE RowNumber = 3
```

Using the CTE you should be able to update the nth number of rows. Play around with this and you should be able to come up with all sorts of solutions.

Answer (score 3):

`row_number` will be as per ordering of `orderingColumn`. So, replace it as required. `@value1, @value2` and `@Nth_Number` are *variables*.

```
update A set column1= @value1, column2= @value2
from ( select column1, column2, 
              row_number() over (order by orderingColumn) rn from yourTable) A
where rn  = @Nth_Number
```

if your `value1, value2` are *columns* then try as

```
update A set column1= value1, column2= value2
from ( select column1, column2, value1, value2
              row_number() over (order by orderingColumn) rn from yourTable) A
where rn  = @Nth_Number
```